# Facebook Feed Dialog at Windows 8 app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, windows-8, microsoft-metro, facebook-javascript-sdk, winjs

Im trying to do a windows 8 app that share a link...

I already have an access token.
how can i open the feed dialog?

I'm using the folowing code:

```
    var facebookURL =
    "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed" +
    "?display=popup" +
    "&app_id=" + FBI.appID +
    "&access_token=" + FBI.auth.getAccessToken() +
    "&link=http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/archery-master/172c7273-10a8-4519-8a66-68ec4dae12f1" +
    "&picture=http://wscont1.apps.microsoft.com/winstore/1x/0a119429-8795-4e0b-9f1a-d55bb5e8c2b1/Icon.70730.png" +
    "&name=Archery%20Master" +
    "&caption=I%20have%20a%20new%20best%20score" +
    "&description=My%20best%20score%20was%20300%20points" +
    "&redirect_uri=" + FBI.auth.callbackURL;

var startURI = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(facebookURL);
var endURI = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(FBI.auth.callbackURL);

Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync(
    Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationOptions.dafault, startURI, endURI)
    .done(function (result) {
        switch (result.responseStatus) {
            case Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationStatus.errorHttp:

                break;
            case Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationStatus.success:

                break;
            default:

                break;
        }

    }, function (err) {

    });
```

But, I'm having the folowing error:

`API Error Code: 110`

`API Error Description: Invalid user id`

`Error Message: Missing user cookie (to validate session user)`

Sugestions?

Answer (score 2):

The optimal pattern for sharing in Windows Store apps is to use the [Share Source contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758315.aspx). This allows your app to choose what to share, while giving the user the choice of where/how to share it (e.g. - which app to share with).

The downside of implementing sharing to a specific provider within your app is the MySpace phenomenon. What happens if the social network you're coding for doesn't outlive your app? You've now got code in your app that you need to maintain, but which has limited value to your users. By the same token, if a new social network arises, you'll then want to add code to your app to share to it.

Using the Share Source contract solves both of these problems by allowing the user to choose the app which receives the shared data. If they wish to share with Facebook, they can choose an app that supports that network. If they prefer Twitter, they can share that.

Unless there's some really compelling reason not to, I'd advise looking into the Share Source contract. You can write less code, and provide the user with more flexibility, and your app will behave the way that users of Windows Store apps expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but im already using the facebook scores api as my backend, so, i need the user authentication to share his score and download friends scores. If i use the share source contract, i will have two diferent UI... I will set this share source contract at the charm bar, but what i want, is an experience more connected with facebook. With the Share Sorce contract, i cant set all facebook parameters that i have at the facebook dialog...

Comment: Are you working from the WebAuthenticationBroker sample on MSDN (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)? And what line of code above is causing the error you're seeing?

Comment: The sample just get the AccessToken, it works fine. What i want is to open another window (after the login) like the login window to open the feed dialog. When i open this new window (with the feed dialog address) the page inside the window show this error (the facebook send this error). I think that the dialog window dont handle the session/cookies, im looking a way to do this

Comment: @Bruno.cf - Ah. If you aren't storing the AccessToken, I believe you need to do that, and provide the token on subsequent API calls.

Comment: Im storing this at function `FBI.auth.getAccessToken()` but facebook want the cookies, not the accessToken...

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the line access_token.

```
var facebookURL =
"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed" +
"?display=popup" +
"&app_id=" + FBI.appID +
//"&access_token=" + FBI.auth.getAccessToken() +
"&link=http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/archery-master/172c7273-10a8-4519-8a66-68ec4dae12f1" +
"&picture=http://wscont1.apps.microsoft.com/winstore/1x/0a119429-8795-4e0b-9f1a-d55bb5e8c2b1/Icon.70730.png" +
"&name=Archery%20Master" +
"&caption=I%20have%20a%20new%20best%20score" +
"&description=My%20best%20score%20was%20300%20points" +
"&redirect_uri=" + FBI.auth.callbackURL;
```

I tried your code, without access_token line, it seems to be able to display the dialog.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you tried it at a windows 8 metro style app? Because this works at the Browser, but not at the application...